# How do I find a role with a specific permission?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I'm trying to create a discord bot and one of the commands for the bot needs me to filter roles by the permissions they're allowed (or, at least this would be the easiest way), and I can't seem to figure out how to do that. I've tried way too many things to even count, and at this point, I'm looking for a different way. But if anyone has the answer to this, that would be amazing.

Basically I wanna do this:

`let staff = message.channel.guild.roles.cache.filter(s => s has this permission)`

(Pseudo-code obviously)

But as I said, I just can't seem to figure it out.

```
            case 'staff':
    
            let staff = chan.guild.roles.cache.filter(m => m.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_MESSAGES));

            
            //console.log(staff)

                message.guild.channels.create(Channel, 'text').then (
                    function() {
                        let ch = message.guild.channels.cache.find(ch=>ch.name === Channel)
                        ch.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, { VIEW_CHANNEL : false });
                        ch.updateOverwrite(staff, { VIEW_CHANNEL : true })
                    }
                )
                type.stop()
            break;
```

Also, 'chan' is a shortened version of 'message.channel'

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
let rolesWithManageMessagesPermission = 
    message.channel.guild.roles.cache.filter(r => r.permissions.has(Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_MESSAGES)
```

Comment: This by itself only seems to either just return an error, or give me the @everyone role, is there something I'm missing?

Namely: 
'Supplied parameter is not an User nor a Role'

I'll edit my question to include the code from the error